# Run WebStorm code directly in browser

Tags: javascript, webstorm

Is there a way to execute the written code in WebStorm directly in browser? For example some plugin for Chrome?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To see the console, you don't need to open up the browser. just hit 'run' or (^R) shortcut.
if it is html or ejs file, just right click on the file and choose 'open in browser' and choose the browser.

Comment: Okay, but I want to run .js file in browser ? It there a way without copy-paste the code?

Comment: use
<script>
window.onload = function{
  //your script goes here  
}
</script>